# Does macOS Mojave comes with java pre-installed?

Tags: macos, terminal, mac, mojave, java

I just ran **which java** command and got the output **/usr/bin/java**

I also executed **java -version** command and also got version information output. So I believe that there is an actual java executable and not just a placeholder kind of thing. I may have installed it at some point, but I cannot remember doing that. Or does it comes pre-installed with the macOS Mojave?

If it doesn't come pre-installed, how do I get rid of it?

Edit:
Below is the output of `ls -l /usr/bin/java`

```
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  74 Sep 25 01:45 /usr/bin/java -> /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/Current/Commands/java
```

Comment: Why do you want to get rid of it?

Comment: Because if it didn't come preinstalled and also if I have no use of it, then it doesn't have to be there.

Comment: Can you add the output of `ls -l /usr/bin/java` to your question`?

Comment: @nohillside, I've updated the question with the command output.

Comment: What did java -version show?

Comment: Is this a clean install of Mojave, or an upgraded one ?? - I have a clean install and I don't have any java under the path you posted for `/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/*`.

Answer (score 6):

Java does not come preinstalled.

The /usr/bin/java command does come preinstalled, though - but it is not Java. Instead it is an Apple program that lets you decide between multiple installed JDKs (if any). If you haven't got a JDK installed, which is how the system is by default, it will tell you via a popup and let you click a button to be directed to a download site for the JDK.